# Python script for text file - string, "[value1, value2, value3]"

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a .txt file (Input): 
inputfilename.txt:

```
{'a':"[25, 27, 13]"
'b':"[50, 57, 41]"
'c':"[37, 33, 23]"
'd':"[40, 38, 24]"
'e':"[11, 11, 11]"
'f':"[2, 0, 2]"
'g':"[6, 4, 3]"
'h':"[79, 85, 39]}
```

I am looking to get an output of:

```
a, 25, 27, 13
b, 50, 57, 41
c, 37, 33, 23
d, 40, 38, 24
e, 11, 11, 11
f, 2, 0, 2
g, 6, 4, 3
h, 79, 85, 39
```

I found an answer to my question, which is below.

*Note:*
I know its possible to use a for loop, but does anyone know of a quicker way because my inputfile.txt is quite large - 7000 rows.

Comment: What's the `ast.literal_eval()` supposed to do there?

Comment: @SirParselot I was looking for a quicker way besides using a for loop because my input file is quite large (7000 rows).

Comment: yes but you use the variable `ast` which is never defined - nevermind I just looked at the python doc

Comment: If this is the only change you need, consider just using something like `replace()` to throw away the quotes and brackets rather than trying what you're doing. If you only have files that you'll have to deal with once, `awk` or `sed` may be even easier.

Comment: @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen `literal_eval()` is a function in the `ast` module.

Comment: yes sorry, should have googled `python ast` _before_ commenting.  my bad.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `replace()` to remove the brackets and the double quotes before you evaluate the file content:

```
temp = dic1.read()
for ch in ('[', ']', '"'):
    temp = temp.replace(ch, '')
super_dic = ast.literal_eval(temp)
```

Comment: it may execute faster using `temp = re.sub('\[|/]|/"',"",temp)` but in both cases a space is not added after the comma so you would likely use `temp = re.sub(",(?! )", ", ", temp)` or `temp = temp.replace(", ", ",").replace(",", ", ")`

Answer (score 0):

I opened my .txt as a dictionary, made the values in dictionary as strings, and then joined the three values, which are now strings. Then started a new line for each. Done through for loop. Fixed the problem!

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys
import csv
sys.stdout=open('outputfilename.txt', 'w')
f=open('/Users/cmdb/Desktop/inputfilename.txt', 'r')

dic = eval(f.read())
with open("outputfilename.txt","wb") as g:
    for key in dic:
        g.write(",".join([key] + [ str(x) for x in dic[key] ] ) + "\n")
```

Comment: Hi there! I see that you've provided an answer to your question. However, you should tell us whether this is the answer to your question. If this is additional code that is a part of the question itself, then you should edit your question to include this. Thanks! :D

Comment: @Zizouz212 Sure, will do :)! Sorry, I am still new to this